What does BackingFieldAttribute do in EF Core?
Microsoft's instance of using BackingFieldAttribute:
public class Blog
{
    private string _validatedUrl;

    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    [BackingField(nameof(_validatedUrl))]
    public string Url
    {
        get { return _validatedUrl; }
    }

    public void SetUrl(string url)
    {
        // put your validation code here

        _validatedUrl = url;
    }
}

At first I had supposed, that it'll create Blog in database with Url attribute, but result is single BlogId column. Then I've read:

Note that backing fields are only discovered for properties that are included in the model. For more information on which properties are included in the model, see Including & Excluding Properties.

It says that in that example Url won't be included in model (hence in database). So BackingFieldAttribute in this example is useless? Url acts here like an ordinary NotMapped class' property, which becomes null after creating new context:
var blog = new Blog();
string url = "some url";
blog.SetUrl(url);
context.Add(blog);
context.SaveChanges();

blog = context.Blogs.First();
Assert.AreEqual(url, blog.Url); // success

context = new testContext();

blog = context.Blogs.First();
Assert.AreEqual(null, blog.Url); // success

When I remove this attribute, everything above works the same way and it looks as if there're no changes.
So what the actual purpose of this attribute? I would like example where this attribute isn't useless.

It doesn't seem to work, at least not with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0 and MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0
